# how to open modal2 from a button of modal1 in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-deployment

I have two modals one is Login modal and another is Signup modal now I want to open signup modal by clicking on a button which is present in login modal, I tried many different ways but not able to achieve it, also I tried to make a signupModalSwitch with useReducer and by making different function calls but it was saying against hooks rule, I am very new to react not able to figure out how to do it. Thanks in Advance :)

modal1 ->

```
function LoginModal() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        onClick={handleOpen}
        variant="outlined"
        className={classNames(
          classes.textNeonGreen,
          classes.outlinedNeonGreen,
          classes.navButton
        )}
        classes={{ disabled: classes.disabled }}
      >
        <Typography noWrap>Login</Typography>
      </Button>
      <Modal
        className={classes.modal}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        closeAfterTransition
        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
        BackdropProps={{
          timeout: 500,
        }}
      >
        <Fade in={open}>
          <LoginCard LoginClose={handleClose} />
        </Fade>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

function LoginCard({ LoginClose }) {
  return (
    <Card className={classes.modalCard}>
      <span>
        <button
          onClick={LoginClose}
          type="button"
          className="close px-2 pt-2"
          aria-label="Close"
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </span>
      <CardContent className={classes.modalCardContent}>
        <Typography variant="h4" className={classes.modalHeading}>
          <b>Login</b>
        </Typography>

        <Account>
          <Login />
        </Account>

        <div>
          <Grid
            container
            direction="column"
            justify="center"
            alignItems="center"
          >
            <p className="mb-2 mt-4 text-center">
              Don't have Account?
            </p>

//###### BY CLICKING THIS BUTTON I WANT TO OPEN MY SIGNUP MODAL #######//    

            <button
              className="btn btn-outline-success btn-block btn-md"
              onClick={() => {
                LoginClose();
                signupModalSwitch(null,{type:'open'})
              }
            }
            >
              Signup
            </button>
          </Grid>
        </div>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

MODAL2 ->

```
function signupModalSwitch(state, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'open':
      return { open: true }
    case 'close':
      return { open: false }
    default:
      console.log(action);  
  }
}

function SignupModal() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(signupModalSwitch, { open: false })

  function handleOpen() {
    dispatch({type: "open"});
  }

  function handleClose() {
    dispatch({type: "close"});
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        onClick={handleOpen}
        variant="outlined"
        className={classNames(
          classes.textNeonGreen,
          classes.outlinedNeonGreen,
          classes.navButton
        )}
        classes={{ disabled: classes.disabled }}
      >
        <Typography noWrap>Signup</Typography>
      </Button>
      <Modal
        className={classes.modal}
        open={state.open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        closeAfterTransition
        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
        BackdropProps={{
          timeout: 500,
        }}
      >
        <Fade in={state.open}>
          <SignupCard signupClose={handleClose} />
        </Fade>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

function SignupCard({ signupClose }) {
  return (
    <Card className={classes.modalCard}>
      <span>
        <button
          onClick={signupClose}
          type="button"
          className="close px-2 pt-2"
          aria-label="Close"
        >
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </span>
      <CardContent className={classes.modalCardContent}>
        <Typography variant="h4" className={classes.modalHeading}>
          <b>Signup</b>
        </Typography>

        <Signup />
        
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this would be to create a container and move all the logic to the container. Your login and sign up modals should be dumb components, i.e, do not maintain the state in these components.

In your container, keep two states, openLoginModal and openSignupModal.

```
 const [openLoginModal, setOpenLoginModal] = useState(false)
 const [openSignupModal, setOpenSignupModal] = useState(false)
```

You can pass these as props to your login and signup components. When you click the button in the login modal, you will need one more function that closes login modal and opens sign up modal. You can pass this as prop as well.

```
const onSignupButtonClick = () => {
   setOpenLoginModal(false)
   setOpenSignupModal(true)
}
```

You can conditionally render login and signup modal based on the state values.